# How to use Mathematica to prove that isotropic materials have only two independent parameters

Tags: group-theory

Posts on related issues can be found from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573187/how-many-independent-parameters-does-the-fourth-order-tensor-have-under-rotation) or [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63937/symmetrizedarray-of-stiffness-compliance-tensor/120099#120099).

---

*Index symmetries:*

A stiffness tensor $C$ is a fourth-order tensor with components $c_{ijkl}$ which maps symmetric second-order tensors into symmetric second-order tensors, i.e., $\sigma_{ij} = c_{ijkl} \varepsilon_{kl}$ (linear elastic law), $\sigma$ (stress) and $\varepsilon$ (strain) being arbitrary symmetric second-order tensors. Due to the symmetry of the second-order tensors, $C$ is allowed to be minor symmetric, i.e., $c_{ijkl} = c_{jikl} = c_{ijlk}$. The not minor symmetric part of $C$ is irrelevant for the elastic law and is dropped. If the stress $\sigma$ is to be related to an elastic energy potential $W$ (referred to as hyperelastic behavior), i.e., $\sigma = \partial W / \partial \varepsilon$, then, due to Schwarz's theorem, the stiffness tensor $c_{ijkl} = \partial^2 W / \partial \varepsilon_{ij} \partial \varepsilon_{kl}$ has to possess the major symmetry, i.e., $c_{ijkl} = c_{klij}$.

*Material symmetry:*

A material with stiffness $C$ is said to possess the material symmetry group $G$ (e.g., triclinic, orthotropic, transversally isotropic, ...) if

\begin{equation}
C = Q \star C  \qquad Q \in G
\end{equation}

holds, where $Q$ are second-order tensors, referred to as symmetry transformations of $C$. The product $\hat{C} = Q \star C$ (referred to here as Rayleigh product) is defined in components as

\begin{equation}
\hat{c}_{ijkl}
= Q_{im}Q_{jn}Q_{ko}Q_{lp}c_{mnop}
\end{equation}

For solids, $G$ is a subset of the orthogonal group. In solid mechanics, if suffices to consider rotation matrices $Q$ from the rotational group $SO(3)$. If $G = \{I\}$, $I$ being the identity matrix, then $C$ is said to triclinic. If $G$ possesses more than the identity transformation, then different material classes can be defined (different anisotropy types). If $G = SO(3)$, the $C$ is said to be isotropic (no direction dependency).

---

**I want to use Mathematica to get the number of independent parameters needed for the fourth-order tensor to make $C = Q \star C  (Q \in  SO(3))$ under the rotation of group $SO(3)$.**

At present, I can only get 30 independent variables using the following method:

```
SymmetrizedIndependentComponents[{3, 3, 3, 3}, 
  Symmetric[{1, 2, 3}]] // Length
```

However, I still can't use the rotation of group $SO(3)$ to further reduce the number of independent variables. What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Summary

There are 3 independent degrees of freedom for the tensor $A_{abcd}$ if it is invariant under Rayleigh transformation, and it also satisfied $A_{abcd}=A_{cdab}$. The independent components can be taken as $A_{2332},A_{3223},$ and $A_{3322}$. If we further require that $A_{abcd}=A_{bacd}$ (and/or $A_{abcd}=A_{abdc}$), the number of independent components reduce to 2, which can be taken as $A_{3223}$ and $A_{3322}$. By direct analysis, we can actually see that

> $$A_{abcd}=A_{3322}\delta_{ab}\delta_{cd}+A_{3232}\left(\delta_{ac}\delta_{bd}+\delta_{ad}\delta_{bc}\right)$$

**Note:** Below, I'll detail a Mathematica implementation to get this result via using invariance under $SO(3)$ through explicit transformation. However, in practice, we do not need Mathematica to get this result. As we are trying to construct a rank-4 invariant object, $\delta_{ab}$ is the only $SO(n)$ invariant tensor that we can use ($\epsilon_{abc}$ is no use here), hence one can immediately make the ansatz
$$A_{abcd}=a\delta_{ab}\delta_{cd}+b\delta_{ac}\delta_{bd}+c\delta_{ad}\delta_{bc}$$
which is what we got through Mathematica anyway. We can get the result above from this by imposing $A_{abcd}=A_{bacd}$, hence the result that there are 2 independent components does not really need Mathematica computation.

---

### Details

One straightforward, albeit not elegant, method is to simply utilize the invariance under $SO(3)$ explicitly.

Let us illustrate this with a simpler example by trying to find a $3\times3$ matrix invariant under rotations: $A_{ab}=M_{ac}A_{cd}(M^T)_{db}$, or analogous to the way you wrote down the Rayleigh product, $A_{ab}=M_{ac}M_{bd}A_{cd}$. To find this matrix, we first define `RayleighProd2[i_, input_]` which does this transformation:

```
RayleighProd2[i_, input_] := 
  TensorContract[
    TensorProduct[RotationMatrix[Sequence @@ i], 
      TensorContract[
        TensorProduct[RotationMatrix[Sequence @@ i], input], 
      {2, 4}]], 
  {2, 4}];
```

This basically takes an input matrix $A_{ab}$ and takes it into $M_{ac}M_{bd}A_{cd}$ where the rotation matrix $M$ is specified by the first argument of `RayleighProd2`, which will be a list of the form `{a,v}` where `v` is the the vector pointing rotation axis and `a` is the angle of rotation.

If we require that this transformation is an identity transformation, that means that the matrix $M_{ac}M_{bd}A_{cd}$ should be independent of `a` and `v`. For practical purposes, we consider this transformation for all three orthogonal axes for arbitrary angle `a`, and then take the derivative wrt `a`: the resultant tensor should be zero for any `a`, which we will fix to 0 for convenience. We define this operation as

```
ClearAll[casesToBeChecked];
casesToBeChecked[input_] := Block[{\[Theta]}, 
   Flatten[D[
      Flatten[Table[
         RayleighProd2[{\[Theta], v}, input], 
      {v, {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}}]], 
   \[Theta]]] /. \[Theta] -> 0];
```

We can now find the form of the matrix $A_{ab}$ invariant under these rotations:

```
Array[a, {3, 3}] /. Solve[casesToBeChecked[Array[a, {3, 3}]] == 0]
(* {{{a[2, 2], 0, 0}, {0, a[2, 2], 0}, {0, 0, a[2, 2]}}} *)
```

We immediately see that $A_{ab}=c\delta_{ab}$. QED.

We can extend this approach to OP's case as follows:

```
RayleighProd4[i_, input_] := 
  TensorContract[
   TensorProduct[RotationMatrix[Sequence @@ i], 
    TensorContract[
     TensorProduct[RotationMatrix[Sequence @@ i], 
      TensorContract[
       TensorProduct[RotationMatrix[Sequence @@ i], 
        TensorContract[
         TensorProduct[RotationMatrix[Sequence @@ i], input], 
        {2, 6}]], 
      {2, 6}]], 
    {2, 6}]], 
  {2, 6}];
```

and

```
casesToBeChecked[input_] := Block[{\[Theta]}, 
   Flatten[D[
      Flatten[Table[
         RayleighProd4[{\[Theta], v}, input], 
      {v, {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}}]], 
   \[Theta]]] /. \[Theta] -> 0];
```

For which

```
Array[a, {3, 3, 3, 3}] /. Solve[casesToBeChecked[Array[a, {3, 3, 3, 3}]] == 0]
```

gives the form of the tensor:

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  a(2,3,3,2)+a(3,2,3,2)+a(3,3,2,2) \\
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  a(3,3,2,2) \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
>  a(3,3,2,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  a(3,2,3,2) \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  a(2,3,3,2) \\
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
>  a(3,2,3,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  a(2,3,3,2) \\
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  a(2,3,3,2) \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  a(3,2,3,2) \\
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  a(3,3,2,2) \\
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  a(2,3,3,2)+a(3,2,3,2)+a(3,3,2,2) \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
>  a(3,3,2,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
>  a(3,2,3,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  a(2,3,3,2) \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
>  a(2,3,3,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  a(3,2,3,2) \\
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
>  a(2,3,3,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  a(3,2,3,2) \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
>  \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  a(3,3,2,2) \\
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  a(3,3,2,2) \\
>  0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right) & \left(
> \begin{array}{c}
>  0 \\
>  0 \\
>  a(2,3,3,2)+a(3,2,3,2)+a(3,3,2,2) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

We can see that it depends on only 3 independent variables:

```
DeleteCases[
  Flatten[Array[a, {3, 3, 3, 3}] /. Solve[casesToBeCheckedNew[Array[a, {3, 3, 3, 3}]] == 0]], 
0] // Union
(* {a[2, 3, 3, 2], a[3, 2, 3, 2], a[3, 3, 2, 2], a[2, 3, 3, 2] + a[3, 2, 3, 2] + a[3, 3, 2, 2]} *)
```

Now, we can impose further constraints regarding the symmetries of $A_{abcd}$. For example, we see that

```
A = Array[a, {3, 3, 3, 3}] /. Solve[casesToBeChecked[Array[a, {3, 3, 3, 3}]] == 0][[1]];

Union[DeleteCases[Flatten[Transpose[A, {2, 1, 3, 4}] - A], 0]]
(* {a[2, 3, 3, 2] - a[3, 2, 3, 2], -a[2, 3, 3, 2] + a[3, 2, 3, 2]} *)
```

which means the independent number of variables reduces to 2 if we require $A_{abcd}=A_{bacd}$. The same constraint appears for $A_{abcd}=A_{abdc}$, so the independent parameter number is still 2:

```
Union[DeleteCases[Flatten[Transpose[A, {1, 2, 4, 3}] - A], 0]]
{a[2, 3, 3, 2] - a[3, 2, 3, 2], -a[2, 3, 3, 2] + a[3, 2, 3, 2]}
```

Finally, the symmetry $A_{abcd}=A_{cdab}$ seems to be already satisfied:

```
Union[DeleteCases[Flatten[Transpose[A, {3, 4, 1, 2}] - A], 0]]
(* {} *)
```

Comment: In my calculation, I used `casesToBeChecked` for `RayleighProd2` and `casesToBeCheckedNew` for `RayleighProd4`. I edited them in the final version above.

Comment: Thank you very much. and I can't find the definition of `casesToBeCheckedNew` function in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

```
C0 = Normal@
   SymmetrizedArray[
    pos_ :> Subscript[c, StringJoin[ToString /@ pos]], {3, 3, 3, 
     3}, {}];

nvn4[A_] := 
  Module[{ip, i, j}, 
   ip = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}};
   Table[A[[ip[[i, 1]], ip[[i, 2]], ip[[j, 1]], ip[[j, 2]]]]*
     If[4 <= i <= 6, Sqrt[2], 1]*If[4 <= j <= 6, Sqrt[2], 1], {i, 
     6}, {j, 6}]];
nvn4::usage = 
  "nvn4[A] returns the normalized Voigt notation of the fourth-order \
tensor A.";
rp[A_, B_] := Block[{n, it, t1}, n = TensorRank[B];
   it = RotateLeft@Range[n];
   t1 = B;
   Do[t1 = TensorTranspose[A.t1, it], {i, n}];
   t1];
rp::usage = 
  "rp[A,B] computes the Rayleigh product of the tensor B with \
transformation tensor A.";


G = {IdentityMatrix[3], EulerMatrix[{Pi, 0, 0}], 
   EulerMatrix[{0, Pi, 0}], EulerMatrix[{0, 0, Pi}], 
   EulerMatrix[{Pi/3, Pi/3, Pi/3}]};

Gsol = Solve[Table[rp[G[[i]], C0] == C0, {i, Length@G}]][[1]];
Cloc = C0 /. Gsol;
dof = Variables@Cloc;
Length@dof
Cloc // nvn4 // Simplify
```

Using the above code, I can only reduce the number of independent variables to three. I don't know how to further reduce the number of independent variables to two.

**Using the following method, I still get at least three independent components:**

```
SymmetrizedIndependentComponents[{3, 3, 3, 
   3}, {{{2, 1, 3, 4}, 1}, {{3, 4, 2, 1}, 1}}] // Length
SymmetrizedIndependentComponents[{3, 3, 3, 
   3}, {{{2, 1, 3, 4}, 1}, {{3, 4, 2, 1}, -1}}] // Length
SymmetrizedIndependentComponents[{3, 3, 3, 
   3}, {{{2, 1, 3, 4}, -1}, {{3, 4, 2, 1}, 1}}] // Length
```

I don't know how to further simplify to get 2 independent components. I need help from others.