# How to prove that isotropic materials have only two independent constants by tensor operation rules

Tags: tensors

I want to use tensor method to prove that there are only two independent elastic constants for isotropic materials. But I can' t get two independent results after reading related posts.

The following resources can be referenced:

**1.[wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law)**

That is to find the invariant linear transformation f under $SO(3)$. For any C belonging to $SO(3)$, 3 * 3 matrix A. There is $C.f(A).C^T=f(C^T.A.C)$, then f can be decomposed into the linear combination of identity, transpose and trace, that is, f = C1 * Identity + C2 * Transpose + C3 * I3 * Trace, I3 is the third-order unit matrix.

**2.[SE community related posts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/63937/symmetrizedarray-of-stiffness-compliance-tensor/120099#120099)**

```
Length[indeps = SymmetrizedIndependentComponents[{3, 3, 3, 3}, sym]]
sym = {{{2, 1, 3, 4}, -1}, {{3, 4, 1, 2}, 1}};
Length[indeps = SymmetrizedIndependentComponents[{3, 3, 3, 3}, sym]]
```

How can I get 2 independent variables?

Comment: You're classmates?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/215938/1871

Comment: This is a well-known fact. Why do you need to prove that? Is it a homework? Otherwise, you can take it for granted.

Comment: @xzczd 您不应该询问这类问题，这属于个人隐私信息。

Comment: 1. 回不回答是你的自由。2. 就我所知这个提问不违反stackexchange的规则，如果有哪条站规说了不能问，还请指出。3. 要是你还是觉得我的评论不合适，大可以flag我前一条评论，让管理员来裁决。

Comment: @xzczd 额，其实我只是不好意思回答这个问题，并不是您的评论有什么不合适或违反规则的地方，感谢您的相关帮助和回复。

Comment: ……你俩根本就是同一个人？不是当然最好，但如果是的话，友情提示：stackexchange对开马甲，尤其是开马甲给自己upvote的行为是有处罚的，不太严重的时候可能还不会管你，但是超过一定限度后，从封禁到删号都有可能，所以，悬崖勒马。

Comment: @xzczd 偷颗白菜不至于用炮轰啊 以后不用这个号给自己点赞 主要是有时候问题多 有个小号分担一下提问频率 可以减少不必要的误会 否则别人觉得我太啰嗦

Comment: @pl 提问频率高低不是问题，只要问题是用心提的就可以。

Comment: @xzczd 额 我感觉我的提问没有恶意，只是我的语言表达能力有限，有时候无法阐述清楚，但是肯定是我发现的问题，我以后在表述和提问质量上多注意，感谢你的指导和帮助。